# Remove marker and at the same time the document in firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

When I create a marker I somehow want the information about the FirebaseFirestore document that is linked to it to follow it, so that later on when I want to remove the marker the FirebaseFirestore marker is removed along with it.

In my case when a marker is pressed and the user longclick's the infoWindow it is supposed to remove the marker but also the document. The logic for the onInfoWindowLongClickListener goes like this:

```
gMap.setOnInfoWindowLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowLongClick(Marker marker) {
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(); // I guess this is needed.
        marker.remove(); // removes marker
    }
});
```

The marker is removed, but I can still see the document in Firestore.

Should I use `marker.getTag()`?

When I create the marker it goes something like this:

```
btnRetrieveMarkers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            db.collection("my_collection")
                    .get()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                for(QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()){
                                    HashMap hashMap = (HashMap) documentSnapshot.getData();
                                    String status = (String) hashMap.get("Status");
                                    GeoPoint geo = (GeoPoint) hashMap.get("Geopoint");

                                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(geo.getLatitude(), geo.getLongitude());

                                    Marker mark =  gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(status)));
                                    mark.setDraggable(true);
                                    // mark.setTag() < -- how to save the info about the document here?
                                    }
                            }else {
                                // TODO: handle error here
                            }
                            if (task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, R.string.no_markers_registered_yet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Update: question has been edited/updated to clarify the purpose, since I wasn't clear enough about it.

Comment: Firestore has an API for deleting documents.  It looks like you're not using it.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data

Comment: @DougStevenson I've don't know how to specify which document it should delete. If I just type db.collection("collectionA").document().delete(); nothing happens - the document is still in Firestore.

Comment: Well, we don't know which document you need to delete either.  There's not enough information here for anyone to associate the marker to the document it came from.

Comment: @DougStevenson that is my problem - I don't know how to transfer / get the information..

Comment: @DougStevenson I've updated my question, so it should be more clearly now. Please reconsider downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete the marker's firestore document using only the marker, tag the marker when it is created with its firestore document id.

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
  ...
);

marker.setTag("[document id]");
```

When you want to delete it:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

String markerId = (String) marker.getTag();

db.collection("[name of the collection]")
.document(markerId)
.delete();
```

You may also want to implement [OnMarkerClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener) to get the selected marker when clicked.

Comment: This is correct - with a little adjustments. I will edit your answer so that it is correct. Thanks!